# Resolution of getusermedia javascript not mobile's one

Tags: javascript, camera, resolution, getusermedia

I'm doing a website to take a photograph with the mobile phone and process it for recognition.

Here is the code of the javascript:

```
// Set constraints for the video stream
var constraints = { video: { facingMode: "environment", width: { ideal: 3000 }, height: { ideal: 3000 } }, audio: false };

// Define constants
const cameraView = document.querySelector("#camera--view"),
      cameraSensor = document.querySelector("#camera--sensor"),
      cameraTrigger = document.querySelector("#camera--trigger")
// Access the device camera and stream to cameraView
function cameraStart() {
    navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then(function(stream) {
        track = stream.getTracks()[0];
        cameraView.srcObject = stream;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Oops. Something is broken.", error);
    });
}
// Take a picture when cameraTrigger is tapped
cameraTrigger.onclick = function() {
    cameraTrigger.disabled = true;
    cameraTrigger.style.visibility = "hidden";
    cameraView.pause();
    track.stop();
    cameraSensor.width = cameraView.videoWidth;
    cameraSensor.height = cameraView.videoHeight;
    cameraSensor.getContext("2d").drawImage(cameraView, 0, 0);
    document.getElementById("imagen").value = cameraSensor.toDataURL("image/jpeg",1.0);
    document.getElementById("bot").click();

};

window.addEventListener("load", cameraStart, false);
```

I set the ideal width and height to 3000, that is enough for what I'm looking for, before that I had the problem that it looked for some standard resolutions and the quality was too low.
However, this is only working for one mobilephone.
I'm trying with different mobiles and I only get 3000x3000 images with one one+ that has the best camera. The other mobiles return an image of 2000x1000 more or less, but their camera is of 13Mpx and if I take the photo with the app the result is 4000x3000.

Any idea? Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are observing the way these `.getUserMedia()` constraints work when you give `ideal` values. Your browser's, and device's, video input subsystem does its best to match what you want. But if it cannot match what you want, it will give you what it can do.

If you give `exact` constraints, for example like this, you can make `.getUserMedia()` fail rather than give you something different from what you want.

```
var constraints = { 
             video: { 
                    facingMode: "environment",
                    width:  { exact: 3000 }, 
                    height: { exact: 3000 } },
            audio: false };
```

When your web app is intended to run on lots of different devices you can do something like this to make it fail if the camera subsystem just isn't good enough for your application.

```
var constraints = { 
             video: { 
                    facingMode: "environment",
                    width:  { min: 1920, ideal: 3000 }, 
                    height: { min: 1080, ideal: 3000 } },
            audio: false };
```

In all cases you must, as you did, look at `.videoWidth` and `.videoHeight` to determine what the camera subsystem actually gave you.

Apps designed for webcams and mobile device cameras must be flexible about the dimensions of the pictures they receive. The quality and resolution capability of cameras in the wild is highly variable.

A web app which demands very large image dimensions is unlikely to be very useful in the wild, sad to say.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I will try what you say. However, my question was more about (I didn't explain very well) why if the mobilephone has enough resolution, ```.getUserMedia()``` is not able to give that resolutions? Maybe because is video instead of photo?